# Sub-bullets using Verdana are not the right size in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists, font-face

This might be really picky, but a person in QA pointed out to me that sub-bullets are tiny when using Verdana in IE: http://jsbin.com/IQEmEq/2

The first list is using the default browser style, the second list is using Verdana. Notice the sub-bullet in the first list has a normal size, i.e. it is the same size as the other bullets in the list. But in the second list the sub-bullet is smaller than the other bullets.

Chrome and Firefox seem to render all the bullets the same size regardless of font, but IE for some reason doesn't.

How can I "fix" this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be something they introduced in IE 9: the bullets may depend on the font. As far as I can see, the sub-bullets are the same size in both lists, but in the Verdana list, they *look* smaller, partly because the primary bullets are big, partly because Verdana test is big.

I guess Microsoft regards this as a “fix” to something. It seems that they use U+25E6 WHITE BULLET as the default secondary bullet, and it is oddly small in Verdana (when compared to other characters). Previously, I suppose, IE used bullets taken from a specific font, no matter what had been set in CSS.

So in a sense, it’s design flaw in the Verdana font.

One way (though not the most elegant way) to get list bullets you want is to include them into document content, without using `ul` markup. You can get a basic bullet using `&bull;` and a secondary bullet (ring) using `&#x2218;` if you want a bigger circle in Verdana. (U+2218 is RING OPERATOR, so it’s a somewhat illogical choice.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's probably as close to a fix as I'm going to get, but there's no way I'm going to replace all my ul elements. QA will have to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact they introduced the behavior in IE8 already. For me it's just the contrary: when the LI's font is Arial, the bullets are smaller, even rectangular, and with Verdana they're of regular size. 
If you want to fix lists in many documents you can use either css or javascript that will fix the lists when the page loads.